# Grass GIS r.to.vect: Prevent neighboring cells with equal values from being unified

Tags: grass-gis, vectorization

I've got different satellite image bands as GRASS rasters, which I want to convert to vector dataset. As I want to compare the IDs of the cell polygons later on, the neighboring cells with coincidentally equal values should NOT be unified to one polygon like this:

[image]

Is there a way to prevent this case? I can't use the '-v' flag to use raster values as categories since I just need the unique IDs later on.